# Top n in nested grouping using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, top-n

**Goal**: Grouped by quarter and name I want to have the top n names by count (see example below). So the desired output for top 1 (for the example below) would be:

```
2019 Q1  Klaus 2
2019 Q2   Karl 3
```

As this is just a toy example going forward I also want to have the top 4, 5 etc by count per quarter and name.
Do you have any good ideas how to implement this with `data.table` (no `dplyr` please). Many thanks!

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x = c("2019 Q1", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q1", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2", "2019 Q2"),
                 y = c("Klaus", "Gustav", "Klaus", "Karl", "Karl", "Karl", "Stefan"))

# Structure of dt
# x      y
# 1: 2019 Q1  Klaus
# 2: 2019 Q1 Gustav
# 3: 2019 Q1  Klaus
# 4: 2019 Q2   Karl
# 5: 2019 Q2   Karl
# 6: 2019 Q2   Karl
# 7: 2019 Q2 Stefan


dt[, .N, by = .(x, y)]

# Output:
# x      y N
# 1: 2019 Q1  Klaus 2
# 2: 2019 Q1 Gustav 1
# 3: 2019 Q2   Karl 3
# 4: 2019 Q2 Stefan 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first calculate the N per name and quarter and then order the data.table and afterwards pick the first n rows per quarter:

```
dt[, .N, by = .(x, y)][order(-N), head(.SD, 1), by = x]
```

Comment: nice one, hadn't thought about `head()` not leading to `NA` when a top_n does't (fully) exist in every group... Will keep this in mind for my own work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(y~x,dt,function(v) as.matrix(head(data.frame(sort(table(v),decreasing = TRUE)),1)))
        x   y.1 y.2
1 2019 Q1 Klaus   2
2 2019 Q2  Karl   3
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another `data.table` approach, almost the same as Gilean's answer, but without `head()`.

```
dt[, .N, by = .(x,y) ][ order(-N), .SD[1:1], by = x ]

#          x     y N
# 1: 2019 Q2  Karl 3
# 2: 2019 Q1 Klaus 2
```

Comment: @RonakShahm yes it will... :)

Comment: The reason why I added `head()` is that if OP wants to get the top 4 or 5 names per quarter, then this solution would add additional rows with `NAs` if there are not so many names per quarter.

Comment: @Gilean0709, I understand. Depends on OP's usecase I guess ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `data.table`:

```
dt[, .N, by = .(x, y)][, .SD[N==max(N)][1], x]
```

or better

```
dt[, .N, by = .(x, y)][, head(.SD[N==max(N)], 1), x]
```